# How could I return the result (of Applescript) to next workflow?

Tags: applescript, automator

sorry for I am a newbie in Applescript & Automator.

I had been created a workflow (using Applescript) to get snapshot from some website (by Firefox+Add-on "page saver" +hotkey).
But I wish to pass the image to next step of workflow for another process.

How do I do next ?

```
   tell application "Firefox"
   open location "http://xxx.xxx.xxx"
   activate

   tell application "System Events"
       keystroke "d" using {control down}
       -- take snapshot
   end tell
   delay 2
   close every window of application "Firefox"
   tell application "System Events"
       keystroke return
   end tell
   end tell
```

Comment: Is the next step in the workflow another AppleScript?

Answer (score 1):

This is sloppy, yet it works.

In the page saver preferences, save your screenshots to:
/Users/Mark/Documents/Twin

```
main()

on main()
set screenshotFolder to (alias "Mac OS X:Users:Mark:Documents:Twin:")

tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    open location "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    delay 3

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "d" using {control down}
        delay 2
        set latestDate to creation date of file 1 of screenshotFolder
        repeat with i from 2 to count of (list folder screenshotFolder)
            if creation date of file i of screenshotFolder is greater than latestDate then
                set latestDate to creation date of file i of screenshotFolder
            end if
        end repeat

        -- The targetFile is what you are looking for
        set targetFile to every file of screenshotFolder whose creation date is latestDate
    end tell
end tell
end main
```

Comment: Yes, I had a similar thought. My initial thought was to ask the Finder to get the "name of files" in the screenshotFolder. You do that before you take the screenshot and then do it again after. Then loop through the second list checking the names against the first list. When you find a name that isn't in the first list... that's your new file. Similar idea as yours.